# In git, can I compare my last n commits to a branch with the current HEAD of that branch, excluding commits from others?

Tags: git

Normally I'd work in a git feature branch let one of my colleagues review my work before merging it to `master`, but I had to do some work directly in the `master` branch, so all of my commits are now interspersed with commits from others. I'd like to produce a `diff` between the current `HEAD` of the `master` branch and my previous *n* commits to `master`, so that my colleagues can review my work as if it was a single commit or patch. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do that directly. I believe that the simplest solution 
would likely be to create a temporary branch, then use `git rebase -i` naming 
the commit you want to use as the original in your diff as the argument.  In 
the editor which that spawns reorder the commits so that yours appear after the 
other commits.  You may also want to squash your commits.  At that point you 
can easily get a single diff of your changes.